# Variable scope in node.js or casper.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, phantomjs, casperjs

I feel stupid asking this question. But I have an annoying issue with variable scoping `aaa` below. Shouldn't it output `test` at the end? But that wasn't the case. What did I do wrong to use `aaa` within a function?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var aaa = 'test';
casper.start('http://google.com/', function() {
    this.echo("I'm in");
});

casper.run(function(aaa) {
  this.echo(aaa);
  this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you echo out `aaa`, it uses the `aaa` as defined in the first parameter for your function.  If your first parameter was called `bbb` or something, then you would see the output that you expect, as it would use the `aaa` defined in the outer closure.

Comment: @HP. This business where a symbol masks (obscures, takes precedence over) a symbol defined in the enclosing scope is called "shadowing". E.g., the `aaa` argument to your `echo` function "shadows" the `aaa` declared globally.

Comment: Just to add some clarification to Brad's answer: Inside of a function, passing in a variable is like defining it with the var keyword. So var aaa = 'test'; function(aaa){} is like saying var aaa = 'test'; function(){ var aaa = 'something else'; }